# How to test POST request with Guzzle PHPUnit without comitting to DB

Tags: api, unit-testing, phpunit, guzzle, web-api-testing

I am learning how to implement API unit testing with PHPUnit and Guzzle but I am a bit lost as to how to implement a POST request without actually committing anything to the database.

There are some tutorials how to send a POST request, but I would like to know if there is a way to rollback the transaction or simply call the api without actually writing anything to the DB?

Comment: If you want to mock some (external?) API call that you are doing with guzzle , you can take a look at the [Testing Guzzle Clients](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/testing.html). Hope this help

Comment: Look at "mock" concepts, you can simulate a behavior for an object